# Entender error '13' en tiempo de ejecución para corregirlo

Tags: excel, vba

Estudio la lógica de los Bucles Anidados en VBA de Excel 2016.
Estoy probando el código del enlace https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7exlHzymDY&t=1056s

Este es el código:

```
Sub simpsonnestedloop()
Dim custTotal As Currency, custName As String
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, oRow As Integer
oRow = 11

Range("A1").Select

For r = 2 To ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row
    Cells(r, 2).Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(Selection)
        custTotal = custTotal + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    Loop

    If custTotal > 0 Then
        custName = ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).End(xlToLeft).Value
        Cells(oRow, 1).Value = custName
        Cells(oRow, 1).Value = custTotal
        custTotal = 0
        oRow = oRow + 1
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Sin embargo, al correr el código paso por paso, VBA muestra este mensaje:

> "Se ha producido el error '13' en tiempo de ejecución. No coinciden
>   los tipos".

Ese error 13 se muestra en la siguiente línea de código coloreada de amarillo:

```
custTotal = custTotal + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

He buscado sin éxito por ayuda en la web  para corregir ese error.
Alguien puede ayudarme a entender ese error y cómo corregirlo.

Answer (score 2):

El propio mensaje de error te da la pista "No coinciden los tipos"

Sucede que es necesario que el tipo de dato de la celda que en ese momento esta seleccionada `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value` , sea igual al tipo de dato de la variable donde se sumara `custTotal`,si el dato de esa celda es texto, entonces no es igual al tipo de dato de la variable, en este caso la variable `custTotal` es de tipo `Currency`, es decir, el tipo de dato de la celda tiene que ser numero, no texto.

Así que tienes que asegurarte que las celdas que recorrerá el bucle tienen solo números o en su caso hacer una validación para comprobar que el dato es numérico.

```
If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)) Then
    custTotal = custTotal + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
End If
```

Cabe mencionar que recorrer un rango de esa manera ( Seleccionando celdas ) es sumamente lento, es mejor usar un ciclo `For Each`, algo como esto:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim custTotal As Currency
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("A1").End(xlDown).CurrentRegion
        custTotal = custTotal + r.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

Una vez que domines esto, puedes dar el paso al manejo de ciclos trabajando con datos en memoria, que es aun mas rápido.

A continuación un ejemplo donde los datos de un rango se ponen en memoria y se usa un ciclo `for` para recorrer esa matriz.

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim custTotal As Currency
    Dim data() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    data = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        custTotal = custTotal + data(i, 2)
    Next i
    Debug.Print custTotal
End Sub
```

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda.

Comment: La respuesta está muy bien Nolberto, pero si está estudiando los bucles anidados y te cargas uno de los dos igual se lía. Quizá sería conveniente que le añadas el bucle para la `j = 1 to x` para las columnas...

Comment: Tienes Razón Damian, aunque en la primera parte de mi respuesta se debe solucionar su problema del error que esta obteniendo, la otra parte ya es a manera de recomendación para mejorar la velocidad de procesamiento cuando se usan ciclos.